# qliksense: measures are not showing the right numbers

Tags: pivot-table, dimensions, measure, qliksense

Qliksense measures issue:

I have a report basically containing a table with data coming from purchase invoices with the following fields:

```
creation_date
expect_Rcpt_date
buy_From_vendor
quantity
Unit_cost 
amount
project_Nbr
```

I have added a pivot_table and a graph next to it to display a measure of summaries on `amount` (calculated using `quantity` X `unit_cost`). I want to visualize by year and vendor, but however all vendors show up the same number, being the total number.

Any help please??

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a term to aggregate the information

if this is your existing code

```
quantity * unit_cost
```

change it to

```
sum(quantity * unit_cost)
```